# How the data will be stored/saved in memory

Tags: usb, memory, storage

Consider I have a USB flash memory with capacity of 8 GB. That is, it can store 8 billion bytes or 8 billion * 8 bits (approximately).

How those huge amount of data can be stored in a small USB flash memory?

I've heard that each bit should be exclusively stored in a snip called *flip-flop*. So there should be (about) 8,000,000,000 * 8 flip-flops in such a tiny USB flash.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes. I asked it above! There is some question(s) mark(s) there!

Comment: and I have a 64GB flash drive.  your question is?

Comment: My question was _How those huge amount of data can be stored in a small USB flash memory?_. It's above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "flip-flop" is a very basic electronic component and is, by modern standards, too low density for use as a memory device.

Modern flash memory cells store data using a variant of a Field Effect Transistor (FET) called the [Floating Gate Transistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Floating-gate_transistor) or FGMOSFET.  In an FGMOSFET there are effectively two gates, one of which is "floating" and is not connected to anything.  In the process of writing to a memory cell electrons are injected onto the floating gate using a high voltage/current.  Erasure happens in a similar fashion but instead sucks electrons off the floating gate, this process is much more damaging than the writing though and actively breaks down the insulation around the gate of the memory cell.  It is the damage done during this erasure that determines how many times the cell can be re-written.  Check the [Flash Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#NOR_flash) page on Wikipedia for a lot of good info.

[image]
<sub>"Flash-Programming" by David W.</sub>

Flash memory cells are typically of the order of 3 square micrometers per NAND cell according to [page 10-8 in this pdf](http://smithsonianchips.si.edu/ice/cd/MEMORY97/SEC10.PDF) (which is a good read if you are interested in the subject). Chances are with more up to date manufacturing that size is much smaller but in theory a 10mm square area would fit somewhere of the order of [3.3 million cells](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how+many+6+square+micrometers+in+10mm2) (ignoring space needed for data lines and control logic).

The next thing is that you could potentially stack sets of cells on top of each other to increase data density and so multiply your storage capacity that way.

Flash also has newer methods where you control how many electrons get injected onto that floating gate and so you end up with multiple levels of charge on the gate, this gives you a multi-level cell or [MLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell).  The problem is that this again multiplies the amount of storage space available but significantly reduces the number of times each cell can be rewritten.